# How to define a custom naming convention if EF 5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, naming-conventions

Suppose that I have a database with 1 table named `Products`. So, I go through the Db First approach and create an EF model in VS 2012 with `pluralize and singularize` option.

So, the model creates a `Product` entity for me, and default naming convention maps this entity to the `dbo.Products` table.

Now I want to change this behavior. In fact I want to create a custom convention to map `ProductModel` entity to the `dbo.Products` table.

Is this possible?! If so, how?

**Update:** My goal to do it...

As you know, whenever you update your model from database, if it causes a change in your model, the auto-generated entities will be over written.

From the other hand, I want to add data annotation attributes to entity properties so that I can use them to shape my views and want to simply work with my DbContext like the following insert:

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(product);
    }
```

the problem is that my application analysis isn't completed and the database changes times to times. So, I need to update the model from the database and after that, all my attributes will removed.

So I decided to create a `ProductModel` class and copy the `Product` codes to it, and pass it the views as view model. Then, whene I want to query my db, I'll get an exception which says that the `dbo.ProductModels` name is not exist in the db...

Thanks in advance

Comment: No...! I can, but I don't want to tweak the .edmx and it's entities

Comment: So then now I'm completely lost as to (a) what you want to do, and (b) what your question really is..... the only *conventions* I know of are the custom conventions that EF **6** will bring to code-first development. Nothing else exists, I'm afraid

Comment: Dear friends! I updated my Q and add some explanations...

Comment: Why can't you just **extend** the generated *partial class* by adding a second file using `public partial class Product { ..... }` and add your custom code there??

Comment: I don't know how to extend that. and I also don't understand the trick you said. tell me how pls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a database-first approach will always map a table name to an entity of the same name (possibly pluralized/singularized). There is currently no provision in EF to tweak that by conventions or tooling. You can change/adapt/customize your model - but if you regenerate it, those changes are lost. I'm not aware of any tools/scripts/hacks to somehow "preserve" those changes and re-apply them after regenerating the model from the database.

If you need to extend the generated I'd suggest using the fact that those are **partial** classes - you can *extend* the generated class in a second physical file :

Write this in a separate file, e.g. `ProductExtension.cs`:

```
public partial class Product
{
   // add your custom methods etc. here
}
```

Those various files that make up that class will be merged together into **one class** by the C# compiler for you.

If you need to add data annotations to existing generated classes, you can use the MetadataType(..) attribute [as shown in this SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736494/add-data-annotations-to-a-class-generated-by-entity-framework):

Write this in a separate file, e.g. `ProductExtension.cs`:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetaData))]
public partial class Product
{
}
```

and then define the metadata/data annotations for your products class in yet another file, `ProductMetadata.cs`, like this:

```
public class ProductMetaData
{
    [Required]
    public int RequestId {get;set;}
    //...
}
```