# Type in auto-generated pluralized name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I appreciate this is purely semantic and pedantic, but...

`EF` has pluralized my table:

`tblPhotoShootItemUploadedPhoto`

as

`tblPhotoShootItemUploadedPhotoes`

(For those who's mother toungue isn't English, it should be `tblPhotoShootItemUploadedPhotos` - no `e` at the end before the s)

What is the easiest way to change this so that it doesn't get incorrectly pluralized again when I regenerate the `edmx` file?

I am generating the `edmx` from an already existing database.

Comment: Are you using EF code first?

Comment: It *appears* the answer is no, you can't override it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761810/how-to-define-a-custom-naming-convention-if-ef-5

Comment: EF6 provides a Pluggable Pluralization & Singularization Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edmx designer,

1. Click on the table.
2. Change the Entity Set Name in the table properties.
3. Regenerate your Context.

This is in EF6, not sure about EF5.

[image]