# Web API and EF cause InvalidOperationException

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have 3 projects in my solution: DataModel (EF), DAL which works with Entities from DataModel and MVC Web API.

There are only 2 very simple entities: Person, Address with 3 simple fields in each of them and Person has the Address field (so these 2 entities are linked)

In my DAL I have a method that returns me the list of all the Persons, the content is very simple: return context.Person.ToList();

Now In my Web API I'm simply calling for the GetPersons() method and trying to return it.
And here I get a strange error message:

> "An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1'
>   type failed to serialize the response body for content type
>   'application/json;
>   charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"$id":"2","Message":"An
>   error has occurred.",...

When I debug I can see that I do have the data from my GetPersons method.
I also googled and found the only solution: I should have added the following lines into my start config:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

But it does not help.

I also tried to populate the list manually without using the database: and in this case it works.

I have a strong impression that it has something to do with EF but I don't know exactly what's that.

Answer (score 5):

- Step by Step guide...

**Step 1:** Go to your Entity Project and then find the name of the class which inherits from DbContext class.

For Example: If the class name is MyProjectEntities as follows:

```
public partial class MyProjectEntities : DbContext
{
   //Auto Generated statements if EF is used.
}
```

**Step 2:** Go to your WebApi Project find the controller which inherits from ApiController and then create the instance for the MyProjectEntities class within that controller.

For Example: If the Api Controller name is PersonController then create the instance for MyProjectEntities as follows:

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
   MyProjectEntities DB = new MyProjectEntities();
}
```

**Step 3:** Create constructor for the PersonController class and set false to the ProxyCreationEnabled Property as follows:

```
public PersonController()
{
   DB.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

The final code within the web api controller looks similar to this:

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
   MyProjectEntities DB = new MyProjectEntities();
   public PersonController()
   {
      DB.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
   }
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by cross references between Person and Address entities when serializing data. You should also add  this line

```
json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
```

More from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664257/why-in-web-api-returning-an-entity-that-has-a-one-to-many-relationship-causes-an)

Comment: Still getting the error:  {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"$id":"2","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Error getting value from 'address' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.address....

Answer (score 0):

You may change Get method your api return a list of objects with ToList(), ToArray() etc.

For Example if your Get Method like this.

```
public IQueryable<Language> GetLanguages()
{
  return db.Languages;
}
```

You can change it to

```
public IEnumerable<Language> GetLanguages()
{
    return db.Languages.ToArray();
}
```

To return Array of objects and free from serialization error. But correct way to solve this problem  is told [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) detailed.