# entity framework database first working on models

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am using entity framework db first. how do I add data annotations to the model without putting it into the auto generated model?

I want to avoid losing the work I have done, in case I need to add a new column to the table.

Any small explanation or link would be helpful for me to understand.

thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a second partial class that is created by you which includes the data annotations you like.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736494/add-data-annotations-to-a-class-generated-by-entity-framework) for an answer covering this issue.

Comment: great that was really what I needed. thanks again. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Code first migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you Biplov13. i may change to code first later on. I am testing database first currently. think code first makes more sense as you can do much more and get more control. I am trying to understand the benefits of db first.thanks :)