# ASP.NET Core MetaDataType Attribute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I'm using the MetaDataType Attribute on my domain model class. It it supposed to move the attribute information from the referenced class into the class that the MetadataType attribute has been set. 
But it doesn't do as advertised. What is causing the issue here?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ComponentModelMetaData))]
public partial class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Repo> Repos { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }   
}


public class ComponentModelMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Name length should be more than 3 symbols.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Repo> Repos { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Both of your classes need to be wrapped by the exact same namespace your Entity Framework classes use. Then it should work fine. This bug through me for a loop until I added it. Then it works! Also, you will need both references: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

Answer (score 87, accepted):

ASP.NET Core uses

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc **ModelMetadataType**
```

instead of

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.**MetadataType**
```

[source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a78f77afde003c4a3fcf5dd7b6dc13dd9c85f825/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelMetadataTypeAttribute.cs)

Try changing your attribute to `[ModelMetadataType(typeof(ComponentModelMetaData))]`

Comment: My deepest thanks for finding  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelMetadataTypeAttribute for .NET Core 1.0 ... different name, different namespace ... not hard to find.  Anyway, this is the correct answer, since the partial class Component appears to be the model declaration.  I prefer to use a partial class named the same and in the same logical namespace as the model to apply Validate and the metadata's annotations to the model.  That way, if I regenerate the model from the database, I don't lose my edits.

Comment: This solution still applies to net core 3.0

Comment: man this sort of thing is brutal, every time I change to some new tech like asp.net core I keep hitting these snags for weeks. I wish there was a way to compile them all somewhere (i.e. "10 Things that will sneak up on you, waste your time, and make you feel inadequate when switching to ASP.NET Core")

Comment: Also thanks for the answer on this one. 1 down, 9 to go :)

Comment: ugh. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc should only be at the web level. I hate having to push this into some business area

Comment: I would give you 2 votes if I could, just spent about 45 minutes wondering why it MetadataType wasn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Entity class:

```
namespace CoreProject.Persistence.EFCore
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Reader = new HashSet<Reader>();
            Writer = new HashSet<Writer>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHashKey { get; set; }
        public byte Role { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedUtc { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdateUtc { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ActivatedUtc { get; set; }
        public bool Test { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Reader> Reader { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Writer> Writer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Metadata (Both have to use the same namespace):

```
namespace CoreProject.Persistence.EFCore
{
    [ModelMetadataType(typeof(IUserMetadata))]
    public partial class User : IUserMetadata
    {
        public string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }

    public interface IUserMetadata
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
        int UserId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        string Password { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        string PasswordHashKey { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        byte Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way... use same namespace

```
public class ApirolesMetaData
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


[ModelMetadataType(typeof(ApirolesMetaData))]
public partial class Apiroles
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation, where the database existed before the coding began.  So DB first seemed the natural choice.  Generated classes, none of which have annotations.  So added `MetadataType`, and found this stackOverflow page - and so tried `ModelMetadataType`.  I tried it against a class, as well as an interface.

I tried using `var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model);`

instead of `var editContext = new EditContext(model);`

and got further when I used `var result = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, xxxxx, validateAllProperties: true);`

I thought I figured it out when I tried `editContext.AddDataAnnotationsValidation();`

Although this works for a class with annotations, it doesn't work (for me) for partial classes using either `[MetadataType]` or `[ModelMetadataType]` attributes.

The only work-around I've found to work (for me) is to create a new class that wraps the model you're wanting to annotate.  That means same properties but getters and setters pointing at original model.  But at least the annotations will work!

```
public class Model
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AnnotatedModel
{
    private readonly Model model;

    public AnnotatedModel(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int ID { get => model.ID; set => model.ID = value; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 10, ErrorMessage = "Name can't be longer than 10 characters.")]
    public string Name { get => model.Name; set => model.Name = value; }
}
```

So to use the above, I needed to write this:

```
var model = new Model();
var annotatedModel = new AnnotatedModel(model);
var editContext = new EditContext(annotatedModel);
editContext.AddDataAnnotationsValidation();
var result = editContext.Validate();
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm missing, great!   Otherwise I hope this work-around will be useful for somebody.

Comment: I feel your pain. They've got to quit breaking stuff like this. It makes getting any actual work done, so hard. Anyway, found a solution: TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(
            typeof(Model), typeof(ModelMetadata)), typeof(Model));