# Why is Entity Framework data annotation not getting picked up

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following solution structure:

(Project) AppNameSpace.Model

- ModelValidation.cs
- WebModel.edmx

Inside `ModelValidation.cs` I have

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CMPlan.MetaData))]
public partial class CMPlan
{
    internal class MetaData
    {
        [Range(100.0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Invalid number of people.")]
        public double peopleCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to save with `peopleCount` less than 100 but the it passed through. The question is how do I instruct it to pick up the validation ?

**Edit**

The following syntax also did not help:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CMPlanMetaData))]
public partial class CMPlan
{
    public int newProperty {get;set;} // This, however, shows up like expected
}

public class CMPlanMetaData
{
    [Range(100.0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Invalid number of people.")]
    public double peopleCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the following for code examples which cover proper 'arrangement' of the `partial class` the metadata class and the association between them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation   I would try it and make it work with the syntax in those examples first before attempting the `internal class` approach for the metadata, as you've shown here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It still ignores the metadata class. Do you have any suggestion where I should look into, something related to configuration ? Any new property in partial class shows up but not the metadata validation.

Comment: An ugly suggestion, but to check if your validation is even being checked, try something like `[Range(typeof(double),"100.00","79228162514264337593543950335")]`. To repeat, this should not be your production code, just as a test.

Comment: ASP.NET Core and MVC6 have introduced `ModelMetadataType` in place of `MetadataType`...You need to confirm or deny if this applies to your scenario.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576921/asp-net-mvc-metadatatype-attribute-not-working

Comment: Thank for the `ModelMetadataType` suggestion, I'm using .NET 4.5 and `MetadataType` is the right one.
@KeyurPATEL Thanks, but it doesn't work at all. 

It doesn't even work when i put it directly on the generated model class. I guess I'm missing something ... but I dont know

Comment: Could you show the view? I guess, you are missing the `jQuery` scripts.

Comment: **_"but the it passed through"_** client-side (jQuery validation) or server-side (EntityFramwork DbContext.SaveChanges - ValidateOnSave) ?

Comment: It passed `DBContext.SaveChanges`