# ModelMetadataType has no effect on model in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, metadatatype

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(ITemporalData))]
public partial class Person : ITemporalData
{

}


public partial class Person
{
        public DateTime SysStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime SysEndDate { get; set; }
}

public interface ITemporalData
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        DateTime SysStartDate { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        DateTime SysEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is example of sample code.

ModelMetadataType has no effect (DatabaseGenerated data annotation doesn't added to the appropriate properties). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576921/asp-net-core-metadatatype-attribute-not-working?

Comment: No! I use ModelMetadataType instead of MetadataType

Comment: ModelMetadataType is connected to model binding/validation in MVC - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelmetadata?view=aspnetcore-2.0
you are probably searching something for EF. Probably you will have to go through docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro.
You are maybe missing Database Context, context is not registered or database is not initialized on startup context.Database.EnsureCreated();

Comment: It is hard to guess what are you missing with so little code. You can share your code or you can go through this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro
and figure out what part of db initialization is missing.

Comment: @IvanMilosavljevic: When I debug, person.GetType().DeclaredProperties[0].CustomAttributes.Count() = 0. The attribute doesn't added to the property. What matters Database.Context ?

Comment: As I Know
ModelMetadataType is just an indirection mechanism. "Find this thing in that other class with this type and name, and apply these attributes to it.

Comment: @IvanMilosavljevic: If you want, I can attach the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156182/discussion-between-ivan-milosavljevic-and-aram-gevorgyan).

Answer (score 4):

```
Asp.Net Core Web Api


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;


[ModelMetadataType(typeof(IPerson))]
public partial class Person : IPerson
{

}

public partial class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public interface IPerson
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```