# How to transfer DataAnnotations from model to viewModel in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations

In my ASP.NET Core project, How can I transfer DataAnnotation attributes from Subject to SubjectViewModel without duplicating them?

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name MaxLength is 200")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class SubjectViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add the attributes to the properties. This isn't duplication - the two classes have nothing in common as far as the language is concerned. A *ViewModel* is specific to its view or views too and can contain data from multiple entities or DTOs. The validation requirements of a *View*model aren't the same as the model behind it. Different actions and commands have different validation requirements as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

The annotations for the view model and the view model are different.

For the view model you want the attributes that deal with data annotation of the the view, while in the underlying model you want attributes that deal with the persistence layer, usually related to Entity Framework.

Note that EF expects the `MaxLength` attribute, while ASP.NET Core MVC expects the `StringLength` attribute.

```cs
[Table("Subjects")]
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class SubjectViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name MaxLength is 200")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.Multiline)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I want to transfer attributes that not deal with the persistence layer.
I do this in asp.net mvc  by adding [MetadataType(typeof(Subject))] to view model class,but this not work in asp.net core

Comment: [`MaxLengthAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute) also works for MVC validation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576921/asp-net-core-metadatatype-attribute-not-working You should use `ModelMetadataType` instead of `MetadataType`.