# EF Core ignores ModelMetadataType

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We are using `.NET Core 2.2`. We used the database first approach with data annotations. We have the following model:

**Issue.cs**

```cs
[Table("issue", Schema = "abc")]
public partial class Issue
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Column("summary")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

**Issue.partial.cs**

```cs
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(IssueMetaData))]
public partial class Issue
{
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
}

public class IssueMetaData
{
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
}
```

If I run the following query ...

```cs
var issue = _dbContext.Issue.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2406);
```

I get the following error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '42703: column x.IsPublic does not exist'

It looks like the metadata class is ignored. If I move `[NotMapped]` to `public partial class Issue` in `Issue.partial.cs`, it works normally. Both partial classes are in the same namespace.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`ModelMetadataTypeAttribute` is part of [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelmetadatatypeattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and exists in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace and corresponding dll. EF Core does not depend on ASP.NET Core, so it does not know anything about this attribute and can't analyze it.

As [@Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) suggested in comments you can use [fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#use-fluent-api-to-configure-a-model) to configure your model in `OnModelCreating` method in your context. Something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().Ignore(c => c.IsPublic);
}
```

Comment: Is there any workaround to what I am trying to do? `IsPublic` is calculated property based on other properties from `Issue`.

Comment: @Mark what is wrong with moving `NotMapped` to the class itself?

Comment: @Mark also you could try to use [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MetadataTypeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute?view=net-5.0)

Comment: If I move `NotMapped` to the class itself, I can't add attributes to properties that already exist in automatically-generated file (`Issue.cs`) because of duplicate definition.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576921/asp-net-core-metadatatype-attribute-not-working, .NET Core uses `ModelMetadataType` and not `MetadataType`.

Comment: @Mark according to the link _**ASP**_.NET Core uses `ModelMetadataType` (also as I wrote in my answer), I don't see any problems with ASP.NET Core mentioned in the question, I see problems with EF Core. Also  I believe you can add both attributes to the `Issue` in `Issue.partial.cs`

Comment: I installed `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` v5.0.0 and added `[MetadataType(typeof(IssueMetaData)]` to the class definition, but it says that `The type or namespace name 'MetadataTypeAttribute' could not be found`.

Comment: @Mark EF core already is dependent on `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` see in the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/). Not sure why you needed to install it. Check that you are installing the same version as you EF Core/Npgsql EF Core package does

Comment: @Mark only noticed that you are using .NET Core version  2.2. Install corresponding version  of `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` (I would try one 4.5-4.7 range preferably  matching the one with EF Core installation)

Comment: I tried `4.5.0`, `4.6.0` and `4.7.0` and neither of them contains `MetadataTypeAttribute`.

Comment: It's simple - EF Core does *not* use either. Or more generically, does not support data annotation indirection (like EF6 ). Use fluent API instead.