# How to keep DataAnnotations Attributes separately?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

EF 5 is used in MVC training application and ADO.Datamodel is created with two tables (Employee, Department).

[image]

Where to maintain Data annotation attributes like Required etc. I tried the below data annotation in auto generated department.cs, is working fine but after Update Model from database these annotation is gone. how to keep separate?

[image]

Thanks your suggestion.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736494/add-data-annotations-to-a-class-generated-by-entity-framework

Comment: And this http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation

Comment: Thanks Steve.. working fine