# OData V4 using Vocabulary Annotations to pass data annotations

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, data-annotations, wcf-data-services, odata-v4

Does anyone know how to set / read vocabulary based annotations in the metatdata for OData V4 to define things like max string length?

There is an article [Client Annotation Support](http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#04-05-client-annotation-support) but it does not show any sample code and I'm not 100% sure they are even talking about data annotations.
It has code like the following:

```
var person = dsc.People.ByKey("russellwhyte").GetValue();

// Try to get an annotation for a property
dsc.TryGetAnnotation<Func<ObservableCollection<string>>, string>(() => person.Emails, fullQualifiedTermName, qualifier, out annotation);
```

But it does not explain what to use for "fullQualifiedTermName" or "qualifier".
I am adding the "odata.inculde-annotations=*" but that does not seem to help.

I have also tried the following.

```
dsc.TryGetAnnotation<Func<string>, string>(() => person.FirstName, "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations", out annotation);
```

But that only returns null.

I found an article [Vocabularies in WCF Data Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2011/10/13/vocabularies-in-wcf-data-services/) from 2012 that talks about support for validation metadata.
I'm going to give it a shot.
I would hope there is an easy / better way of doing this in OData V4.

**Update 1**
Well the WCF vocabularies example does not work in OData V4 because the config.AnnotationsBuilder is missing from System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.

OData V4 supports Vocabularies as defined here http://www.odata.org/vocabularies/ and even offers what I need "metadata annotation may define ranges of valid values for a particular property" but there does not seem to be any sample code on any articles other than SAP https://blogs.sap.com/2013/10/07/vocabulary-based-annotations/ using it.

**Update 2**
Well after looking at the [TripPinService](http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(dykeblgaiywboggjsh4ed45o))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata) I noticed that they had some annotations on budget like the following.

```
<Property Name="Budget" Type="Edm.Single" Nullable="false">
    <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Measures.V1.ISOCurrency" String="USD"/>
    <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Measures.V1.Scale" Int="2"/>
</Property>
```

Luckily the source code for that project is [ODataSamples TripPin](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/Scenarios/TripPin/src/odatalib)
After looking over the service I found that I first have to create my own xml vocabularies file. (ValidationVocabularies.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
  <edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Org.OData.Validation.V1" Alias="Validation">

      <Term Name="StringLength" Type="Edm.String" AppliesTo="Property">
        <Annotation Term="Core.Description" String="Set max length of string." />
      </Term>

    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

In the WebApiConfig file I must get to the xml file and add the vocabulary annotation to the metadata.
Again I was lucky in that the source code for TripPin had a nice helper class for this. (I modified it to look like the following)

```
public static class DataValidationHelpers
{
    public static readonly IEdmModel Instance;
    public static readonly IEdmTerm StringLengthTerm;

    internal const string StringLength = "Org.OData.Validation.V1.StringLength";

    static DataValidationHelpers()
    {
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin") + @"\App_Start\ValidationVocabularies.xml"))
        {
            IEnumerable<EdmError> errors;
            System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stream);

            CsdlReader.TryParse(reader, out Instance, out errors);
        }

        StringLengthTerm = Instance.FindDeclaredTerm(StringLength);
    }

    public static void SetStringLengthAnnotation(this EdmModel model, IEdmProperty property, int length)
    {
        if (model == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
        if (property == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("property");

        var target = property;
        var term = StringLengthTerm;
        var expression = new EdmIntegerConstant(length);
        var annotation = new EdmVocabularyAnnotation(target, term, "StringLength", expression);
        annotation.SetSerializationLocation(model, EdmVocabularyAnnotationSerializationLocation.Inline);
        model.AddVocabularyAnnotation(annotation);
    }

}
```

I then call this from inside the GetEdmModel() method like the following:

```
var target = ((EdmEntityType)edmModel.FindDeclaredType("Test.Models.Person")).FindProperty("FirstName");  
((EdmModel)edmModel).SetStringLengthAnnotation(target, 50);
```

It would be nice if anyone knows how to get to the property by the Name rather than some string value.
I did try builder.EntityType().Property(p => p.FirstName) but that type is not of IEdmProperty.
Anyway moving on...
So now where use my browser to get to the $metadata I can clearly see the string length attribute on the FirstName.

```
<Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String">
<Annotation Term="Org.OData.Validation.V1.StringLength" Qualifier="StringLength" Int="50"/>
</Property>
```

This is nice but now on to the next problem. How to get to it from the client?

Well at first I tried.

```
DbContext.TryGetAnnotation<string>(personQueryResponse.FirstName, "Org.OData.Validation.V1.StringLength", out annotation);
```

But that gives me the following error.

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element
>   Then I tried:

```
DbContext.TryGetAnnotation<Func<string>, string>(() => personQueryResponse.FirstName, "Org.OData.Validation.V1.StringLength", out annotation);
```

But annotation is null.
I noticed that calling TryGetAnnotation does not call the OData service again.
So I then thought I would have to read the client side CSDL file so I then looked back at the WCF article but they don't tell you where they got the "annotations" collection.

I'm still digging but this is becoming a lost cause.
Such a shame that Microsoft wanted to push OData out as such a great service but there is little documentation and a very small support group.
I have 4 open OData questions and very little hits.
Don't get me wrong, I love OData, but this is a love / hate relationship.

**Update 3**
My current workaround is to create a partial class that looks like my entity and then create an interface to contain the data annotations.
[Add data annotations to a class generated by entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736494/add-data-annotations-to-a-class-generated-by-entity-framework)